# putMapping illegal_argument_exception without message

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I try to call putMapping from elasticsearch javascript client, but always got an error with status code 400, illegal_argument_exception.

When I call getMapping for "documents" index I got:

```
 {
"documents":{
    "mappings": {
         "properties":{
              "category":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword": 
                         {"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},
              "createdAt":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":                                          
                         {"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},
              "id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":                                                                  
                         {"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},
              "info":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword": 
                         {"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},
              "text":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword": 
                         {"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},
              "title":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword": 
                         {"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},
              "visibility":{"type":"boolean"}
            }
    }
}
}
```

I tried to call putMapping with same properties and add a new parameter 'index': 'not_analyzed' to category field:

```
esClient.indices.putMapping({
            index: 'documents',
            type: 'document',
            body: {
                document: {
                    properties: {
                        title: { type: 'text' },
                        info: { type: 'text' },
                        text: { type: 'text' },
                        category: { type: 'text', index: 
                           'not_analyzed' 
                        },
                        visibility: { type: 'boolean' },
                        createdAt: { type: 'text' },
                    },
                },
            },
        }, (err, resp) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Successfully Created Index', resp);
            }
        });
```

I got this error:

```
ResponseError: illegal_argument_exception
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/user/reference_sys_cfu-back/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:287:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1168:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  name: 'ResponseError',
  meta: {
    body: { error: [Object], status: 400 },
    statusCode: 400,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'content-length': '345'
    },
    warnings: null,
    meta: {
      context: null,
      request: [Object],
      name: 'elasticsearch-js',
      connection: [Object],
      attempts: 0,
      aborted: false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

index: 'not_analyzed' - I do this for use "term" method for exact finding strings, but it (index: 'not_analyzed') deprecated in 2.x version of elasticsearch. Now I just use field.keyword: 'query string', to finding exact strings.